# How to use \psrotate?

Tags: pstricks, pstricks-add

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
\pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}

\pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
\pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
\pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
 \def\figA{\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)}
 \figA%
%\psrotate(I){-50}{\pspolygon(3,3)(2,1)(5,1)}%
\psrotate(I){-50}{\figA}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

With `\psrotate(I){-50}{\pspolygon(3,3)(2,1)(5,1)}` , I get

[image]

With `\psrotate(I){-50}{\figA}` , I don't get anything

[image]

Assume that `A=(3.2783,3.5876), B=(1.07368,-1.235), C=(7.777,-1.3336)`.

How to get the output without calculating M and N ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\psrotate` doesn't work with nodes (Nodes are fix points in the current system).

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-eucl}%
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](0,-3)(8,4)
    \pnodes(3,3){A}(1,-1){B}(7,-1){C}
    \pstMiddleAB[PosAngle=135]{A}{B}{M}
    \pstMiddleAB{A}{C}{N}
    \pstMiddleAB{M}{N}{I}
    \def\figA{\pspolygon(A)(M)(N)}
    \figA
    \pstRotation[RotAngle=-50]{I}{A,M,N}[a,m,n]
    \pspolygon[linecolor=red](a)(m)(n)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]